# Which version spring portlet is applicable for liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6.2

I developed one spring portlet with version 3.0, while i added the portlet into panel pages it showing below error:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-9][AdvancedPermissionChecker:618]
   com.liferay.portal.NoSuchResourceActionException: #CONFIGURATION
   com.liferay.portal.NoSuchResourceActionException: #CONFIGURATION
```

So for Liferay 6.2, which version spring is accepted? Any body any idea?

Comment: FYI :- LR 6.2 uses Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE

Comment: Check this https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4633431

Answer (score 0):

The supported version of Spring for Liferay 6.2 is 3.0.7.RELEASE.
See the following discussion on the subject:

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4633431